# PHP memory limit issues repeats after the updating to a bigger size

Tags: magento2, php, memory

I have updated the memory limits to 1024M in the php.ini file in the root directory however while installing the extension, am still getting the error stating to update the memory to 756M or above.

Am using magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

For magento2, minimum 2GB memory limit required.

I don't think  php.ini file changes reflect on your system.

On magento2 root dir, create a  file `phpinfo.php`  and rewrite below code
`<?php phpinfo();?>`

After that browse this php file and check memory limit.

**You may need to change memory limit at server php.ini file**

Comment: Just "<?php phpinfo();?>" in the blank file? I have done so. Memory limit is set to 2048M in the php.ini file. Will this work now?

Comment: `"<?php phpinfo();?>" ` yes.

Comment: Done. Problem still exists.